# CSS Layout (div height)

Tags: html, css

I think my question would be quite simple but I can't figure out what's wrong with my style sheet.

I would like to design my website layout as follow.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nkw5.jpg

I can achieve it by this.

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: White;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: White;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: Blue;
}
#global_nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: Orange;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
#local_nav {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
#main {
    width: 580px;
    height: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
    background-color: lime;
}
#footer {
    background-color: Gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            Header
        </div>

        <div id="global_nav">
            Navigation Bar
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="local_nav">
                Side Bar
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                Main Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, as my website is dynamic, the information in main content is come from database so the height need to be dynamic too.
I tried to remove "height:300px;" in content or main, but I failed to keep the same design.
What's wrong with the code?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C8RQ5/3/)**

**CSS**

```
   html,body{
    height:100%;
   }
    #content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display:table;
    }
    .local_nav {
        width: 200px;
        display:table;
        float: left;
        background-color: green;
        height:100%;
    }
    .main {
        width: 580px;
        float: right;
        background-color: lime;

        height:100%;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"> Header </div>
  <div id="global_nav"> Navigation Bar </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="local_nav"> Side Bar<br/>
      Side Bar<br/>
      Side Bar<br/>
      Side Bar<br/>
      Side Bar<br/>
      Side Bar<br/>
      Side Bar<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="main"> Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"> Footer </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @pk028382 Welcome you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
```

in #main so it adjust its height according to content and for the side bar, i think you need to use faux columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: White;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: Blue;
}
#global_nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: Orange;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 220px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 220px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 220px);
    height: -ms-calc(100% - 220px);
    height: -o-calc(100% - 220px);
}
#local_nav {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
#main {
    width: 580px;
    height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background-color: lime;
}
#footer {
    background-color: Gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
```

LIVE DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/nandhakumarsri9/zAcAr/